# Как преобразовать список в строку?

Tags: python

Если открыть текстовый файл с помощью `text.read()`, возвращается список. Можно ли как-нибудь преобразовать его с строку, чтобы дальше работать с ним регулярными выражениями?

Comment: Как раз таки read без параметров возвращает весь файл одной строкой.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
myList = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']
myString = ''.join(myList) # '' - разделитель между элементами списка соответственно

>>> str1str2str3

myString = '_'.join(myList)

>>> str1_str2_str3
```

Comment: Pep-8 рекомендует `my_list`, `my_string` вместо `myList`, `myString`

Comment: Всё верно. Теперь так и пишу.