# Как спушить строки (каждая состоит из нескольких символов) в одну структуру?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно, чтобы строки, состоящие из нескольких символов, собирались в одну. Программа работает как шифратор, получает на ввод фразу на английском, заменяет каждую букву на набор символов (латинские буквы являются ключами к этим наборам в словаре) и возвращает эти наборы символов, но по отдельности (в столбик в командной строке), а нужно, чтобы они собирались в список или строку

```
alph_leet={
    'a':'4',
    'b':'6',
    'c':'<',
    'd':'])',
    'e':'3',
    'f':'}',
    'g':'(_+',
    'h':'/-/',
    'i':'1',
    'j':'_|',
    'k':'|X',
    'l':'|',
    'm':'|v|',
    'n':'|\|',
    'o':'()',
    'p':'|o',
    'q':'()_',
    'r':'12',
    's':'5',
    't':'+',
    'u':'|_|',
    'v':'\/',
    'w':'\/\/',
    'x':'><',
    'y':'-/',
    'z':'>_'

}

for i in s:
    a=alph_leet.get(i, " ")         
    print(a)
```

P.S. А если еще подскажете, как, получив подобное сообщение, его можно было бы расшифровать, буду вдвойне благодарен)

Comment: Весь код из сторонних сервисов нужно перенести непосредственно в вопрос. По коду на стороннем ресурсе невозможно вести поиск, в нем отсутствует подсветка синтаксиса, ссылки имеют свойство протухать. Также приведите пример желаемого поведения программы - желаемый вывод на тестовых данных, пример.

Comment: пример данных на ввод: hello  программа при этом выведет значения ключей по отдельности,а нужно,чтобы одной структурой (  /-/ 3 | | ()    это пример того,что она должна выводить)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать список в строку?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/300050/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собирайте всё в одну строку и выводите:

```
a = ''
s = input()
for i in s:
    a += alph_leet.get(i, " ")
print(a)
```

или выводите по частям, не переводя строку:

```
s = input()
for i in s:
    a=alph_leet.get(i, " ")         
    print(a, end='')
```

Comment: а возможно ли в первом варианте решения сделать так,чтобы не выводились этапы ,в которых строка(начальная) переводится(чтобы сразу перевод был)?