# Вырезание текста из списка

Tags: python, list

Проблема заключается в том, что нужно вытащить из списка, а точнее кортежа текст, который там находиться. Предположим имеется данный код:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
print(a)
```

Вывод кода будет такой:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Требуется, чтобы вывод был как **12345** или **1 2 3 4 5**. Тут разницы не будет. Я использовал метод копирования и удаления символов.

Удаление:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
remove = a.replace("[", "'", "]")
print(remove)
```

Копирование:

```
import copy
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
copy = copy.copy(a)
print(copy)
```

Ничего их этого всего не решает проблему так как в выводе остаются кавычки и квадратные скобки. Есть способы решить проблему, но при этом переменная **a** должна быть без изменений. За ответ или совет буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Попробуйте `print(*a)`. Подробнее про вывод строк из списков здесь: (https://pythonist.ru/3-varianat-kak-skonvertirovat-spisokl/)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать список в строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/300050/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете решить этот вопрос только манипуляциями с форматом вывода. Любые манипуляции только со списком не приведут к желаемому результату - при выводе списка "как есть" у вас всегда останутся скобки по краям списка и запятые между его элементами - так печатается список оператором `print`.

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
print(*a, sep='') # передаём список в print как отдельные переменные с пустым разделителем
print(''.join(a)) # делаем из списка строку, соединив элементы пустым разделителем
```

Вывод:

```
12345
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи видимо, надо знать метод типа `str` `.join`:

```
a = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
print(" ".join(a))
```

даст желанное:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```