# Как в питоне преобразовать список в строку

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть список `['Hello', 'Case']`
Мне надо чтоб он превратился в строку без пробелов `'HelloCase'`.
Как это сделать?

Comment: почитать первые главы любого учебника? поискать описание метода `join`?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как преобразовать список в строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/300050/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 1):

[Строковый метод join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
''.join( ['Hello', 'Case'])
```